# How i connect MySql in android

Tags: android

I am trying to connect mysql in android, but I can't. Are there any alternate ways to developed application without mysql if there is small database needed. And which one is better to use mysql or sqlite and why?

Comment: MySQL?? or u mean SQLite?? clear this first, since both are two way different things

Comment: Where do you want the database? On the device or centrally. If it's on the device your best choice is sqlite. Mysql is not installed on Android (generally) and will probably never be.

Answer (score 0):

You basically give the answer yourself: android has Sqlite built in, so if you need a DB in your app, you have to use SQLite.
The good thing is that it is small (and built in), so that it won't use much of the (limited) memory present on a mobile device.

Comment: in my application Batabase in Centerlized that why i don't use Sqlite ok

Answer (score 0):

You build a rest web service and then use http:// to push to that from your droid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the database in a scenario where your data comes from the Internet, then you would be using `MySQL` (or anything similar, like `MSSQL`) and will be developing web-services in `PHP`, or `JSP` or anything like that, to make  your database available to your app.

If you have to use the database locally, you use `SQLite`

depends on the scenario.

For `SQLite`, refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)